# Shortcut to saving all images off of a page

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, save-as

I've done this shortcut a few times before, with permission, and I'm trying to do it again but I don't remember the shortcut to doing so.

Comment: You mean pressing Ctrl + S to save the web page and all images at a folder? [link](http://webtrickz.com/download-save-all-images-from-web-page-in-chrome/)

Comment: otherwise there are lots of addons/plugins to do that